# Probability Problem involving series summation.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

If probability that $X$ students pass in a class of $N$ students is proportional to $X^2$. Then find the probability that a random student selected has passed.

Comment: What is your try?

Comment: Probability that a random student has passed equals $E(X)/N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $p(n)=kn^2$, then we can find $k$ such that total probability is $1$:
$$1=\sum_{n=0}^{N}p(n)=k\sum_{n=0}^{N}n^2\implies k=\frac{6}{N(N+1)(2N+1)}.$$
Then the probability that a random student selected has passed is given by
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}p(n)\cdot \frac{n}{N}=\frac{k}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N}n^3
=\frac{6}{N^2(N+1)(2N+1)}\cdot \frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}=\frac{3(N+1)}{2(2N+1)}.$$

P.S. Recall that $\sum_{n=0}^{N}n^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{N}n^3=\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Pr[X=x]=cx^2$, we have

$$\sum_{x=0}^{N}cx^2=c \left( \frac{N}{6} \right)\left( N+1 \right)\left( 2N+1 \right) =1$$

which gives $$c= \frac{6}{2N^3+3N^2+N}$$
and 
$$\Pr[X=1]=c$$